# How do I compile .s assembly code in UNIX SPARC 64bit correctly?

Tags: unix, assembly, system-calls

Greetings all. Having problem trying to compile and run this "hello, wold" .s code in sparc UNIX 64bit environment and got $: "hello.s", line 1: error: invalid character (0xef) and etc. on other lines and addresses.
Thought it was ANSI UTF issues, changed and saved and tried both types. Then tried to save file with ECO conversion to UNIX and still hit errors.

Compiled with: gcc -o hello hello.s

```
.data 
.align 4 
string: .ascii "Hello, World!\n"
.text 
.align 4 
.global main 
main: 
mov 1,%o0 
set string,%o1 
mov 14,%o2 
mov 4,%g1 
ta 0 
mov 0,%o0 
mov 1,%g1 
ta 0
```

Great forum!!

Comment: @aaa carp: I used notepad and notepad++ in windows 7 and then push it over to the unix school server. Should I be saving the code differently? Or use any other editor?

Comment: try to copy paste your code segment into UNIX editor (for example vi) directly.  Windows has different text file format, it's hard to say.

Comment: ok case closed. I managed to fix it. It needed to be encoded in UTF-8 without BOM. What is that?!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @jdnhldn Pls answer your own question and mark it the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save it to be encoded in UTF-8 without BOM(Byte Order Mark)